# touchpad drag stops working after sleep (18.04/18.10)

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, synaptics, multi-touch

I have a Lenovo X1 Carbon 5th, on startup the touch-pad works fine, I can click on something with one finger then drag it with the other.

After sleep I can only click but not drag...

I have the Synaptics driver installed, I have tried removing this but problem persists.

If I do this command, it fixes it but breaks the two finger scroll..

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I updated to 19.04 and the problem is fixed! must be the new kernel which has sorted out the trackpad.